# rm: cannot remove '/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new': Bad message

Tags: apt, 20.04, grub2, package-management, dpkg

I get

```
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing: linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

wen running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Edit

```
df -i
Filesystem                           Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                                1005233    655   1004578    1% /dev
tmpfs                               1017091   1317   1015774    1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  13107200 304989  12802211    3% /
tmpfs                               1017091      5   1017086    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               1017091      6   1017085    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                               1017091     18   1017073    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2                            10803  10803         0  100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop3                            10847  10847         0  100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop5                            11777  11777         0  100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop6                             1602   1602         0  100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/loop7                              796    796         0  100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/sdb2                             65536  16393     49143   26% /boot
tmpfs                               1017091     81   1017010    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1                         122101760    250 122101510    1% /media/jeremie/Servarr2
/dev/loop10                           12847  12847         0  100% /snap/core/12725
/dev/loop0                              480    480         0  100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/loop1                            11777  11777         0  100% /snap/core20/1361
```

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /devtmpfs                              795M  3.8M  791M   1% 
/run/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   75G  112G  41% /
tmpfs                              3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop3                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop5                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop6                          71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/loop7                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/sdb2                          976M  929M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                              795M   28K  795M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1                          1.8T  160G  1.6T  10% /media/jeremie/Servarr2
/dev/loop10                        111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12725
/dev/loop0                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/loop1                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1361
```

```
dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-===========================================================-===========================================================-============-======================================================================================================
ic  cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf                                 0.45ubuntu2                                                 all          write a network interface file in /run for BOOTIF
ic  cryptsetup-initramfs                                        2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.4                                          all          disk encryption support - initramfs integration
iF  initramfs-tools                                             0.136ubuntu6.7                                              all          generic modular initramfs generator (automation)
rH  linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic                               5.4.0-100.113                                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-100-generic                       5.4.0-100.113                                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
it  man-db                                                      2.9.1-1                                                     amd64        tools for reading manual pages
ic  overlayroot                                                 0.45ubuntu2                                                 all          use an overlayfs on top of a read-only root filesystem
```

Edit 2

```
apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-'[g|i|m|h]' | egrep -v linux-generic | xargs sudo apt-mark auto
linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic set to automatically installed.linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic set to automatically installed.
linux-image-5.4.0-97-generic set to automatically installed.
linux-image-5.4.0-99-generic set to automatically installed.
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-96-generic set to automatically installed.
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-97-generic set to automatically installed.
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-99-generic set to automatically installed.
```

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amd64-microcode* cryptsetup* cryptsetup-bin*
  cryptsetup-run* i965-va-driver* intel-media-va-driver*
  intel-microcode* iucode-tool* kodi-inputstream-adaptive*
  kodi-inputstream-rtmp* kodi-peripheral-joystick*
  libaacs0* libass9* libbdplus0* libbluray2* libcdio19*
  libcec4* libcrossguid0* libdouble-conversion3*
  libfstrcmp0* libigdgmm11* libiso9660-11* libmariadb3*
  libmicrohttpd12* libnunit-cil-dev*
  python3-pycryptodome* qt5-gtk-platformtheme*
  qttranslations5-l10n* thermald* va-driver-all*
  vdpau-driver-all*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 74 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 871 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 252533 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic (5.4.0-100.113) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-100-generic/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
rm: cannot remove '/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new': Bad message
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit 3

```
sudo rm -f /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new
[sudo] password for jeremie: 
rm: cannot remove '/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new': Bad message
```

```
 du -h --max-depth=2 /boot/
du: cannot read directory '/boot/lost+found': Permission denied
16K     /boot/lost+found
du: cannot read directory '/boot/grub': Bad message
4.0K    /boot/grub
315M    /boot/
```

```
ls -al /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new
ls: cannot access '/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new': Bad message
```

**Do you think that running "Boot Repair" on a USB stick is a good idea?**

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `df -i;df -h` also `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: Oh your /boot filesystem is full. `apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-'[g|i|m|h]' | egrep -v linux-generic | xargs sudo apt-mark auto`  and `sudo apt autoremove --purge` I hope the 2. command is working.

Comment: `sudo rm -f /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` if it is not working please add `du -h --max-depth=2 /boot/` and `ls -al /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` there less kernel, than I expected.  and please make a backup from your data and make sure you have a install media, just for security.

Comment: Please no boot repair. I think something is not okay with your 2.Hardrive (/dev/sdb) You have backup?  if so, boot up a live linux(ubuntu) and try to make a file-systemcheck for /dev/sdb2. there is your /boot. and check the harddrive with smartmontools.